# Node.js making a typed array from a Buffer

Tags: arrays, node.js, buffer, typed-arrays

For the `ws` library, the correct (or at least a functioning) way to send Binary data is like so:

```
var array = new Float32Array(size);
ws.send(new Buffer(array));
```

I also see, in the node docs:

```
new Uint32Array(new Buffer([1,2,3,4]))
```

So I am a little confused. Why would one want to make a new buffer out of a typed array and send that vs why would someone want to make a new typed array from a buffer?

Can typed arrays alone be sent via websockets? This failed in my tests but I could be doing something wrong...

Comment: I am just not sure why the get converted to each other (Buffer -> Array and vice versa).  Why not just stick with typed arrays through and through?

Comment: [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#sending-binary-data) may help